# How to re run the ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: angularjs

Anyone help me out to re-iterate the ng-repeat after some time interval.
I have an array with some time and I am comparing with some server time. After some time I should re-iterate the array manually.

```
$scope.list = {
    "SERVER_DATE_TIME": "2016-05-16T10:04:36.318-05:00",
    "list": [{
        "displayDate": "2016-05-16T10:03:36.318-05:00",
        "pageId":"1"
    }, {
        "displayDate": "2016-05-16T10:02:36.318-05:00",
        "pageId":"2"
    }, {
        "displayDate": "2016-05-16T10:01:36.318-05:00",m
        "pageId":"3"
    }]
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="list in newsList track by list.pageId">
   <span elapsed-time data-datetime="list.displayDate"> </span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$interval(function() {
    // update "SERVER_DATE_TIME" and re run
    $scope.list = angular.copy($scope.list);
}, 1000 * 5 * 60 );
```

So in elapsedTime directive am comparing `SERVER_DATE_TIME` and display date then showing time diff.

This is working fine when I don't put track by because `$$hashKey` is available. But if i put track by `list.pageId`, `$$hashKey` doesn't present in the array and re run is not happening.

Please help me to achieve the task.

Comment: AngularJS will automatically "re-iterate" over the data once the data changes inside the scope.

Comment: By the way you are defining the scope.list variable you should loop on list.list?  Make sure that scope.list is just the array you are looping if that is what you want.  You can parse the result from the server and copy the array of values to scope.list directly.

Comment: Ya, Am using list.list only, Here its typo error. till user call the service, the datas remains same. But in certain time interval i have to update the time

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to "re-iterate" over the data.. you just need to update `$scope.list` and angular will automatically apply it (that's data binding ;)

```
<div class="list" ng-repeat="l in listl.list track by l.pageId">
    <span elapsed-time data-datetime="l.displayDate"> </span> 
</div>
```

Comment: my time should change in regular interval. But my data's remains same

Comment: did you try using $scope.apply() after you update the date ?

Comment: am using $interval(function() {}). So its not required

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to force re-trigger ng-repeat, because your list data hasn't actually changed. What has changed is your server time so therefore 
I believe it would make more sense for the elapsedTime directive to take care of that instead.

You could pass serverTime to the directive something like:

```
<span elapsed-time data-datetime="listItem.displayDate" data-servertime="serverTime"> </span>
```

Your directive would create a watcher on serverTime something like:

```
$scope.$watch('servertime', (serverTime) => {//re-eveluate relative time});
```

In the controller you would do the // update "SERVER_DATE_TIME" in an $interval loop and not have to worry about retriggering ng-repeat.

Comment: So any idea to deal this scenario ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. As you've mentioned in your comments, you are not refreshing the actual data list, or getting new data from a server as far as I understand. Only your time changes, so there is no need to force refresh ng-repeat (**in fact, there should never be a need to do that, you just let angular's data binding and digest cycle do that for you**) This seems to me like more of a 'how do I hack something that I designed badly in the first place' - when you could spend a bit more time understanding how to do things the angular way.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the data `pageId` is not changed, so Angular thinks that this element was already rendered and does not bother rendering it once again. `track by` is used to uniquely identify elements in your list/array. If you use `track by $index`, everything will go fine. Is there any reason why you want to track your elements by `pageId` ?
If you want to sort or to filter, you have to use proper filters instead of `track by`. For example [this one](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) for sorting.

Comment: Ya, am using sorting and filtering by date, If i use $index , It will create issues, Thats why i used like this. Is there any approach to nail it ?

Comment: Yes, that's right $index is not changin either so it won't work. Still didn't get why you are tracking by pageId. I updated my answer for sorting and filtering.